# Java Split String to String arry

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Input: `"   10   50 10 40  50   80   60 20 "`.
I want to convert it into string array then into int array. The problem is that when I split with space, it shows errors as:

- 1st string is `"   10"`
- 2nd string is `" 50"`
- 3rd string is `"10"`

Code:

```
s = line.split(" ");
for(i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    arr= Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
    System.out.println(arr);
}
```

I want it should only string array with no space

- 1st string is `"10"`
- 2nd string is `"50"`
- 3rd string is `"10"`

Comment: `arr= Integer.parseInt(s[i].trim());`.

Comment: `s = line.split("\\s+");`

Comment: @Tunaki. There's problem with your `split`, because it gets `""` at first position and causes `NumberFormatException` in for loop.

Comment: @user Well the OP's code is buggy. The split works correctly: it starts with spaces so, of course, there is going to be an empty string at the beginning.